# Is there way to gracefully stop the spring-boot app in Azure app service after stopping app service?

Tags: spring-boot, shutdown, graceful-shutdown

I have a Java spring-boot app deployed over Azure app service. Whenever I stop app service the spring-boot app does not stop in graceful manner. Can you please suggest a way to stop the spring-boot app in graceful way ?

Comment: Please explore graceful shutdown hook. Also try to add some code snippets and relevant logs to get better help.